# Why not show chinese word in Smartface App Studio IDE?

Tags: smartface.io

Why,

```
function Page1_Self_OnShow() { 
//Comment following block for removing navigationbar/actionbar sample    
//Copy this code block to every page onShow 
    header.init(this); header.setTitle("Page1中国文字"); 
    header.setRightItem("RItem"); 
    header.setLeftItem(); 
    this.statusBar.transparent = true; /**/
}
```

Chinese word not show in Smartface App Studio IDE?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem about the visuality of these kind of characters on Smartface desktop ide. But actually it works fine. About the visual problem, there is a reported bug and it will be fixed with the new versions of Smartface.

But for now, you can show chinese characters on device without any problem. 
I copied your code (the below code):

```
function Page1_Self_OnShow() {
    //Comment following block for removing navigationbar/actionbar sample
    //Copy this code block to every page onShow
    header.init(this);
    header.setTitle("Page1中国文字");
    header.setRightItem("RItem");
    header.setLeftItem();
    this.statusBar.transparent = true;
    /**/
}
```

And this code block looks wrong on ide (this is the bug):
[image]

It should be setTitle("Page1中国文字"); but it is lack of the last " character.
As I said before this is only a visual bug.

When I run this app on device (by using device emulator or publish), it is seen as in the below screenshot:

[image]